# Connecting USB to Raspberry pi and to PC Simultaneously

Tags: usb

Can we connect D+ and D- of an USB to a PC and also to Raspberry pi?
If that is so can we access files on both?

Comment: Of course you can connect a Raspberry Pi to a PC by USB. What does `D+` and `D-` mean? Just connect with an USB cable.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you can not.

> USB devices are not designed to be accessed by multiple hosts at the same time.

Source and more info about physically sharing a USB device https://superuser.com/questions/604911/connect-usb-storage-device-to-2-computers-at-a-time

What you can do is share a USB storage device through the internet, this requires both computers connected to the internet or the same network.

For example, you can plug the USB drive on the Raspberry Pi, and either connect using FTP on it or configure a Samba server to share it on the local network. There are many tutorials for such setups on the internet.

Additionally, if your local modem/router supports USB storage sharing, you may plug the USB device there and share it on the local network.